# Hide new Constituent badges on the all-badges page for current election until after the election (show to the user tho)

Tags: feature-request

One of the reason that some places in the not-Stack Overflow-universe don't share that or when someone voted is to help prevent voter intimidation. On Stack Overflow it's probably not as big of a deal because of the sheer volume of the site, but on smaller sites it can leak information that can lead to bad blood.

I propose that we not show who voted until after the election. Yeah, it's a lot of code for a small badge, but it shows that we have peoples' privacy in mind. Otherwise I can know who has voted so far in the election by just looking for the most recent Constituent badges on a given site.

As [Luuklag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/361484/luuklag) points out, it should not be shown on the user page either as part of this request for the current election. It's fine to show to the user, just not to the not-user.

Comment: Why is it a problem to know who's voted? It's not like we can see who they voted *for*.

Comment: @Randal'Thor this is definitely one of those occasions where I know _that_ something is a problem but not so much _why_ it's a problem. As I said above, it's around voter intimidation, and privacy. I wish I were eloquent enough to properly state what the thing in the back of my mind is, but today is not that day. Hopefully someone can come along and do so. (where's Shog when you really need him)

Comment: I agree with @Randal'Thor here. There is no way to use that information to deduct on what candidate one voted, unless there is only 1 candidate. In that case an entire election is pointless.

Comment: The only thing you can intimidate people to do is vote, when you know someone doesn't have that badge. Which would kind of being a good thing, as we would want people to vote.

Comment: Consider a scenario: John is a super-popular chat user and has +30k rep on the site. John hasn't voted yet, because he's still thinking who he wants his choices to be. The other users can see that John hasn't voted yet and infer something off of that useless bit of data that says he hasn't voted.

Comment: @Luuklag Ironically, [related current HNQ](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/59139).

Comment: To be clear, you should still get the badge as soon as it's awarded. I just want the collective page to not show for the current election.

Comment: Well then you could still visit a persons profile and see if it was awarded or not

Comment: I think the "last seen" on user profiles is more problematic (e.g. *"Last seen 58 mins ago"* on [Jon Skeet's user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) right now). A lot can be inferred from that, especially if logged continuously over a long time (e.g. time spend on Stack Overflow during work hours or "Is on Stack Overflow at 0400 hours local time. What is the matter?").

Comment: Good call.I agree

Answer (score 12):

The inspiration for that badge came from physical stickers (back when I didn't just vote by mail):

[image: "I voted" sticker]

> Here in the US, it’s common to at least get a sticker when voting, a token to wear the rest of the day in recognition of your civic-mindedness. Starting today, we’ll be handing out virtual stickers – badges – for visiting and voting

-- [Election participation badges](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/06/08/election-participation-badges/)

There have been some issues with it in the past (possibility to match up sequence of badges with votes), but votes were randomized in the ballot file to mitigate that issue.

I think it's fine, a bit of civic pride. Wish I had a sticker for the ballot I just dropped in the mail...

Comment: good to know the stv file is randomized.

Comment: The difference I see here is that the "I Voted" stickers are not automatically stuck to people, it's a choice to wear them...

Comment: That'd be a nice option for many badges, @the

Comment: Maybe that's the FR then? Allow me to elect to not have my badges publicly shared?

Comment: Sounds a bit obscure, @jco - I think it'd be more fun to allow you to choose a badge or badges to "wear", where that could mean display in a list, on profile, even on usercard.

Comment: Hmmm ... I smell another FR then ... (this is obviously a much larger concept than the one here, because it's gonna mean a lot of touches I suspect)

Comment: FWIW: a threat model for knowing who voted does exist, but it's much more constrained than knowing *how* folks voted. And realistically, it's dangerous to completely hide voters too: makes it easier to make up votes.

Comment: Agreed Shog, but also to be considered is that existing as a white male, whether in the US or outside, and especially on StackOverflow, is not the same as existing as, say, a black woman. As we want to encourage more community participation, some privacy has to be maintained. I don't have to more than hint at the bubbling pustules of chat that we know goes on regarding how people participate on this site for those of us who know they exist to think about how the conversations must go in those places. Oh to be 14 and on /. again, yeah? (no, I don't want that actually, it was ugly and nasty)

Comment: (also I was never on /. at 14. I barely had a Windows 3.1 computer. /. didn't come about till well after I graduated HS)

Comment: Be careful about suggesting ways to hide folks for their own good; everyone has their own needs and tolerances, but giving folks a choice allows them to choose what is best vs having that assumed for them. Also, '99 was Peak /. IMHO

Comment: I blame @Shog9 for these https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355603/allow-me-to-opt-out-of-having-my-badge-participation-displayed-anywhere https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355604/allow-me-to-choose-a-badge-1-to-highlight-on-my-usercard

Comment: What is the purpose? To get others to vote?

Comment: To encourage voting, yeah @P.Mort - and to recognize participation in the process.

Comment: Since Constituent is one of the candidate score badges, isn't it possible for a candidate to artificially increase their candidate score from what it was at the time they nominated by voting in the current election? Shouldn't it not be awarded until after the election in that case, so the score accurately reflects whether or not they voted in a past election (as it indicates at the time of nominations)?

Comment: How is that "artificial", @sonic?

Comment: @Shog9 Yeah, I realized that would be unclear, so I edited my comment after posting it.

Comment: The badge recognizes voting - so if you nominate in an election and then vote in that election and you've never voted before... Your score will go up mid-way through the election. Just like it will for any of the other actions that trigger badges. There's nothing artificial in voting in an election just because you're running in it.

Comment: I agree that normal user activity improving a score is a Good Thing™ so I'm happy to say just roll with it on that one.

Answer (score 0):

I can get behind this.  Right now, there is a stream of "who-just-voted" details behind that badge.