# Allow me to opt-out of having my badge participation displayed anywhere

Tags: feature-request, badges

Inspired by conversation on [Hide new Constituent badges on the all-badges page for current election until after the election (show to the user tho)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355596/hide-new-constituent-badges-on-the-all-badges-page-for-current-election-until-af)

This proposal is to allow a person to choose to have none of their badges shown publicly. While that sort of defeats the purpose of gamification this is about how a robust and mature site has grown. Some people really want more privacy choices in their lives, and we should be considerate of that.

As part of this proposal I still see value in showing the total-badge-count (the gold/silver/bronze #s) but I leave that up to the community for discussion as well.

Comment: This also means "don't show my recent badges on the recently granted badges list" and "don't show the badge list on my profile page" in case those weren't clear.