# Allow me to choose a badge (1+?) to highlight on my usercard

Tags: feature-request, badges, user-card

Inspired by conversation on [Hide new Constituent badges on the all-badges page for current election until after the election (show to the user tho)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355596/hide-new-constituent-badges-on-the-all-badges-page-for-current-election-until-af)

Allow me to show off a badge (including count) I am proud of on my user-card.

This feature would be opt-in.

**Example:**
[image: an example badge added via inspect-element so I could take a screenshot.]

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168227/display-specific-earned-badges-as-profile-bling

Comment: So is a dupe? @ShadowWizardWearingMask

Comment: No, just related. The older request asks to put something in the user profile, this request asks to put in the user card. Different enough to justify two separate requests. :)